# Android runOnUIThread for Chartboost SDK integration for AGK AppGameKit NDK

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-ndk, chartboost

We're using App Game Kit for one of our apps and trying to remove AdMob so we can go with Chartboost.
AGK uses an interpreter for their language that passes through NDK to java.
They have a class called `AGKHelper` which is the entry point for the commands that currently call Facebook, AdMob, an alert dialogue and some other activities. Each of the methods in `AGKHelper` run events through `Runnable` classes. Here's an example of their procedure to make an alert dialogue:

```
public class AGKHelper {
    //just a sample of what's in there many other methods exist
    public static void ShowMessage( Activity act, String msg )
    {
        RunnableMessage run = new RunnableMessage();
        run.act = act;
        run.msg = msg;
        act.runOnUiThread( run );
    }

}
```

Now the `RunnableMessage` class that creates the alert dialogue.

```
class RunnableMessage implements Runnable
{
    public Activity act;
    public String msg;

    public void run() {
            AlertDialog alertDialog;
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
            alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
            alertDialog.setButton( DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}});
            alertDialog.show();
            }
 }
```

There also exists a `CreateAd()` method that makes ads for AdMob using `runOnUiThread()`, but with a `WindowManager` to show the ads. 
As far as we can tell we MUST use `Runnable` to get the activity going for Chartboost.
We followed Chartboost's SDK integration and we get stuck at creating our `Runnable` for it. All of the `Runnables` that `AGKHelper` uses also refer back to the `NativeActivity` by, we believe, passing it as a parameter to the method like `ShowMessage()` and then doing something with it in the Runnable class for each of these methods. Such as

```
AlertDialog.Builder(act) //for the message
ad = new AdView(act, AdSize.BANNER, pubID); //for AdMob - RunnableAd
feed.dialog(act, "feed", parameters,new DialogListener() {} // for RunnableFacebook
```

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to pass the `NativeActivity` to the Chartboost runnable. We're very inexperienced with java so we're learning as we go and feel like we make progress, but then nothing happens.

Does anyone have a full example of a `Runnable` class that gets Chartboost to show? We'd very much appreciate the help.
I would share more of the `AGKHelper` class here, such as the full `RunnableAd()` method, but it is long and filled with `WindowsManager` setup. `RunnableMessage` is the shortest example I can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been able to get this running with `Intent` and `startActivity()`.

`AGKHelper` class which is the entry point for all commands contains:

```
public static void CreateAd(Activity act, String publisherID, int horz, int vert, int offsetX, int offsetY)
{       
    Looper.prepare();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(act, ChartboostActivity.class);
    act.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

`ChartboostActivity` class:

```
public class ChartboostActivity extends Activity {
    private Chartboost cb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chartboostmain);
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Configure Chartboost
        this.cb = Chartboost.sharedChartboost();

        String appId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        String appSignature = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        this.cb.onCreate(this, appId, appSignature, null);
        //this.cb.setImpressionsUseActivities(true);
        CBPreferences.getInstance().setImpressionsUseActivities(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         this.cb.onStart(this);
         // Notify the beginning of a user session. Must not be dependent on user actions or any prior network requests.
         this.cb.startSession();
         // Show an interstitial
         //this.cb.showInterstitial(); 
         this.cb.showMoreApps();
         finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        //finish();
        super.onStop();

        this.cb.onStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {        
        //finish();
        super.onDestroy();

        this.cb.onDestroy(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         // If an interstitial is on screen, close it. Otherwise continue as normal.
         if (this.cb.onBackPressed())
         {
             finish();
             return;
         }
         else    
             super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

While this seems to work just fine we found it strange that we couldn't use `finish()` to close the loop in `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`. Ideally we'd like to do all of this in a `Runnable` class so that we have access to the activity and can call other methods. If anyone has an example of that it would be greatly appreciated. But this solution appears to work!